# How can I view or clear 'other' storage on iPhone 6s?

Tags: iphone, storage

I have an iPhone 6s with 64 GB of storage and currently over 28 GB are taken up by the 'other' category. I already tried clearing my safari cache, deleting email and message attachments, offloading and deleting apps, and deleting photos and videos. In fact, when I deleted several large message attachments, the messages storage category went down from a little over 2 GB to a little over 1, but the 'other' category increased by about the same amount.

Apple says 'other' is mostly cache files and doesn't need to be manually cleared, but I have no available storage on my phone and and unable to take photos, download more music, etc. 'Other' is taking up almost half of my storage.

[image][image]

Comment: Did you restart the phone ?

Comment: Most of the time you can fix issues like this by backing up your iOS device to your computer, then erase all settings and data (Settings > General > Reset) and then restoring from the backup. Annoying but easy enough and it usually works quite well.

Comment: I tried to, but I can't do that either. See this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388837/my-pc-has-over-200-gb-of-free-storage-but-itunes-wont-back-up-my-iphone-with-64

Comment: @SteveChambers Once I got backup to work, your solution worked for me! Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you can fix issues like this by backing up your iOS device to your computer.

So backup, then erase all settings and data (Settings > General > Reset) and then restore the backup you just made.

Annoying but easy enough and it usually works quite well.